# ASP.NET error handling problems

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and I have a very basic site that I just want to grab all Application Errors and email them to me, while giving the user a error page. I read a lot on the subject and seems to be a lot of information. Below is what I came up with but I'm having problems keeping the Exception in session so I can email it to me.

I keep getting a `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code` on the ex.Message from the Error.aspx.cs file.

Any thoughts?

Global.asax.cs-

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

Error.aspx.cs-

```
public partial class Error : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Exception ex = (Exception)Session["Exception"];
            this.SendEmail(ex);
            Session.Remove("Exception");
        }
    }

    private void SendEmail(Exception ex)
    {
        string body = "An exception occured at "
                    + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
                    + " on " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
                    + "<br />" + ex.Message; //ERROR HERE
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("from@email.com", "to@email.com");
        msg.Subject = "Exception in Portal Website";
        msg.Body = body;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are never setting `Session["Exception"]`, so on your `Error.aspx`, `Exception ex` is always going to be null... and then doing `ex.Message` will throw the `NullReferenceException`. Even if you fix that and appropriately set `Session["Exception"]`, what you are doing isn't ideal.

1. You could just send the email from the `Application_Error` function.
2. Your `Response.Redirect` ([MSDN Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) is going to cause ANOTHER exception (ThreadAbortException)
3. You should look at implementing [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). It is easy to implement and does everything you want to do.

But if all you want to do is fix your code, just move the send email logic to  `Application_Error` and then you don't have to worry about `Session`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will look into ELMAH more, I wasn't sure what it took to get it implemented. I just wanted to use something simple (Thought it would be) for now and see how it works. I will move my email logic to Application_error and see how that works.

Comment: I used something similar to what you are doing for years, so nothing wrong with it. Can setup ELMAH in a matter of minutes though and it has some nice functionality.

Comment: @Zach but I think all you need to do is in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console, run `Install-Package elmah` and ELMAH will be working (logging errors in memory I believe)... needs minor massaging to put those in a DB.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in a similar instance is to throw all exceptions and then in your global.asax uses the Application_Error method to perform any work you need to with the error message.

```
  void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        string exception;
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Exception innerException = ex.InnerException;
                exception = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                exception = ex.Message;
            }

        //Send email here       

            //redirect to error page


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you pushing the exception object to session, why not move the SendEmail method to global.ascx and SendEmail then redirect user to Error page. There are third party plugins like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) that can do all this easily for you with simple configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar bind.  I'm going to check out ELMAH, but my project has a huge restriction on Open Source Projects, yours may to.  Sucks to be me!

In which case I'd suggest creating a logging function for the message that you can call directly from the Global.asax.  Something like:

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
      LogException(ex);
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
 }

 //Somewhere Else
 void LogException(Exception ex)
 {
      WriteExceptionToEndOfTextFile(ex);
      SendEmail();
 }
```

This way if someone decides they want to suppress our exceptions, they can still properly handle the exception.